# `package ams error: old form '\matrix' should be \begin{matrix} \end{align}`

Tags: amsmath, matrices, commutative-diagrams

I am using the following code in my latex editor but is saying `package ams error: old form '\matrix' should be \begin{matrix} \end{align}`:

```
\begin{align}
\matrix{
\mathscr{C} & \overset{F}{ \longrightarrow} & \mathscr{D} 
\cr  \downarrow  && \downarrow 
\cr \mathscr{C} \otimes A & \overset{{\color{red}{F \otimes 1}}}{\longrightarrow} & \mathscr{D} \otimes A}
\end{align}
```

[image]

But if remove `\matrix{}`, then it is perfectly running but in that case the figure is not perfect as above.

Any solution or package that solve the above problem ?

Please don'tsuggest `Tikz-GD` because it is not installed in MikTex in my folder

Comment: I got it. Using `\begin{matrix}...\end{matrix}`, the problem solved. But how to increase arrow sizes ?

Comment: Then why don't you just ask miktex to install `tikz-cd` for you? It **is** worth it.

Comment: note it is `tikz-cd` and it is in miktex (and texlive) not Tikz-GD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could employ the [amscd](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amscd) package, which is part of the `amsmath` bundle, to achieve your typesetting objective. See section 8, "Commutative diagrams", of the [user guide](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) of the `amsmath` package for a tutorial on this package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amscd}    % for 'CD' ("commutative diagram") environment
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % for '\mathsrc' directive
\usepackage{xcolor}   % for '\textcolor' directive
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{CD}
\mathscr{C} @>F>> \mathscr{D} \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\mathscr{C}\otimes A @>\textcolor{red}{F\otimes1}>> \mathscr{D}\otimes A
\end{CD}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also with `xy` package you can obtained the same result of `amscd` package (they are similar).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[all,cmtip,color]{xy}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\xymatrix{
\mathscr{C} \ar[d] \ar[r]^F & \mathscr{D} \ar[d] \\
\mathscr{C}\otimes A \ar[r]^{\color{red}{F\otimes 1}} & \mathscr{D}\otimes A }
```

[image]